# Network manager bug

Tags: networking, network-manager, connection

OK I have asked this before I know BUT it was refereed to another question thread, which fixed it temporarily but its back and that thread I CAN'T ADD COMMENTS DUE TO BEING NEW SO PLEASE DON'T DOWN VOTE ME I NEED THE REPUTATION POINTS! Anyway I have this same issue as the other day, my Wi-Fi connection status is showing that its connected via ethernet when its a Wi-Fi connection!! I ran the command systemctl restart NetworkManager.service and rebooted. It was fine for a day or so then it came back! I ran same command and again all good, this morning yet again its done this! I have again ran the systemctl restart NetworkManager.service command but guarantee it will stuff up again! NEVER had this issue last time I installed 16.04, any ideas? Again PLEASE don't down vote me! I want to build my reputation so I can actually comment! Or should I switch network managers? TIA

EDIT: I SAID PLEASE DONT DOWN VOTE ME!!!!!

EDIT: Out put from `ifconfig -a`

```
jezza@jezza-U36JC:~$ ifconfig -a
ens5      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:ae:c5:64:31:93  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:61044 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61044 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4902173 (4.9 MB)  TX bytes:4902173 (4.9 MB)

wls1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5d:60:a1:a9:97  
          inet addr:192.168.43.34  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::710f:16ee:9eaa:f23f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2209243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1164777 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3109835179 (3.1 GB)  TX bytes:131901242 (131.9 MB)
```

Comment: Please add output of `ifconfig -a` and/or `ip a` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert done it!

Comment: Currently you are connected through Ethernet `wls1` interface, so this is expected.

Comment: I don't follow, I have my hotsot on my phone active. I ran the command systemctl restart NetworkManager.service to rectify the bug as told in another article and it was fine till I shut down and re powered today, I'm thinking maybe find and try another network manager?

Comment: still doing it I have to run that command every time! Thinking of running a different network manager Whats a good one? I ran one years ago I cant remember what one though LOL. What is our there? Nothing valid appears in software center